# How can `fastnetmon` check the special IP when listen the network?

Tags: grafana, fastnetmon

How can `fastnetmon` check the special IP when listen the network?

In the fastnetmon network_list, I listen a network segment:

```
103.193.240.0/24
```

The fastnetmon_client:

```
FastNetMon v1.0 FastVPS Eesti OU (c) VPS and dedicated: http://FastVPS.host
IPs ordered by: packets
Incoming traffic             1 pps  0 mbps      0 flows
103.193.242.73               1 pps  0 mbps      0 flows
103.193.240.168              0 pps  0 mbps      0 flows
103.193.240.175              0 pps  0 mbps      0 flows
103.193.240.174              0 pps  0 mbps      0 flows
103.193.240.173              0 pps  0 mbps      0 flows
103.193.240.172              0 pps  0 mbps      0 flows
103.193.240.171              0 pps  0 mbps      0 flows

Outgoing traffic             1 pps  0 mbps      0 flows
103.193.242.73               1 pps  0 mbps      0 flows
103.193.240.168              0 pps  0 mbps      0 flows
103.193.240.175              0 pps  0 mbps      0 flows
103.193.240.174              0 pps  0 mbps      0 flows
103.193.240.173              0 pps  0 mbps      0 flows
103.193.240.172              0 pps  0 mbps      0 flows
103.193.240.171              0 pps  0 mbps      0 flows

Internal traffic             0 pps  0 mbps

Other traffic                0 pps  0 mbps

Screen updated in:              0 sec 1319 microseconds
Traffic calculated in:          0 sec 170 microseconds
Total amount of not processed packets: 65
Packets received:   10468
Packets dropped:        0
```

You see, there is only shows several IPs there, do not shows all the IPs, how can I find the special IP in the IP segment?

and in the `Grafana` dashboard, it also only shows several IPs:

[image]

I have some questions by the way:

1. Does fastnetmon need the switch's agreement when capture package and data collection?
2. Can `Grafana` shows the special IP by searching it?

Answer (score 1):

Please try this https://grafana.com/dashboards/2237

General part of this dashboard  is a templated element **/^$host$/** which you have to use for selecting exact IP-address.

Query itself prepared like this:

```
SELECT mean(value)
FROM hosts
WHERE direction = 'incoming'
AND resource = 'bps'
AND cidr =~ /^$host$/
AND $timeFilter
GROUP BY time($interval) fill(previous)
```

Result of this query you can see here:

[fnm community edition for dedicated IP](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LUIje.png)

This dashboard suitable for community version of Fastnetmon.

BR, Ed.